# Search in text file and save in Excel

Tags: python, excel

I have a text file with information about 1000 student
So i need to save each student details in an excel sheet

Heres a sample of the data:

```
0000:
     name=Jack
     Age=16
     Grade=90
0001:
     name=Max
     Age=18
     Grade=85
0002:
     name=Kayle
     Age=17
     Grade=92
```

I want to have a result like this:

[image]

Comment: What is your question? If you add a polite question to your issue, the response will be a lot bigger. And tell us about the effort you already did yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite easy using pandas and a dict:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

students = []
student = {}
for line in lines:
    if ':' in line:
        student['id'] = line.split(':')[0]
    elif 'name' in line:
        student['Name'] = line.split('=')[1].replace('\n','')
    elif 'Age' in line:
        student['Age'] = line.split('=')[1].replace('\n','')
    elif 'Grade' in line:
        student['Grade'] = line.split('=')[1].replace('\n','')
        students.append(student)
        print(student)
        student = {}
    
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(students)
df.to_excel("output.xlsx")
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

I always use Word for such a job. With Replace, search for Paragraph Marks and replace them with a Tab-character.

E.g. replace `:[paragraph mark][space][space][space][space]name=` with a `[tab character]`. With that you get rid of all the rubbish and you end up with `0000[tab character]Jack`.

When you're done with all lines of tab separated data, select all the lines with data (make sure not to select empty lines without the three tab-characters, otherwise it won't work) and click on Insert -> Table -> Insert Table... Now the data is converted into a Word table. Just copy the table to Excel and you're done.